# Quadratic Formula in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, math, double, quadratic

I tried creating an x value calculator for the quadratic formula.

Code:

```
var firstXValueVAR = 1.0
var secondXValueVAR = 1.0
var squaredValueVAR = 1.0
var firstOperationValueVAR = "+"
var secondOperationValueVAR = "+"
var constantValueVAR = 0.0

var topFormula = 0.0
 var topFormula2 = 0.0
var bottomFormula = 0.0

var TotalSquaredValue = 0

var bSquared = 0

var totalX = 0.0
var totalX2 = 0.0
```

Next, when I click "Go" to calculate X, I have this, and I'm not really sure what I did wrong, but every time I print X, it says nan, and it also says that for topFormula and topFormula2 (= nan).

```
func updateValues(){
    var secondXValueInt = Int(secondXValueVAR)
    var firstXValueInt = Int(firstXValueVAR)
    var squaredValueInt = Int(squaredValueVAR)
    var constantValueInt = Int(constantValueVAR)
    bSquared = secondXValueInt << 2
    TotalSquaredValue = firstXValueInt << squaredValueInt
    firstXValueVAR = Double(firstXValue.text!)!
    secondXValueVAR = Double(secondXValue.text!)!
    squaredValueVAR = Double(squaredValue.text!)!
    constantValueVAR = Double(constantValue.text!)!
    if operations.contains(firstOperationValue.text!){
        firstOperationValueVAR = firstOperationValue.text!
        if secondOperationValueVAR == "*"{
            topFormula = -(secondXValueVAR) + sqrt(Double(bSquared) - (4 * firstXValueVAR * constantValueVAR))
            bottomFormula = 2 * firstXValueVAR
            totalX = topFormula / bottomFormula

            print(squaredValue)


            topFormula2 = -(secondXValueVAR) - sqrt(Double(bSquared) - (4 * firstXValueVAR * constantValueVAR))
            bottomFormula = 2 * firstXValueVAR
            totalX2 = topFormula2 / bottomFormula

            print(topFormula)
            print(topFormula2)
            print(bottomFormula)

            print("X = \(totalX) & \(totalX2)")
        }
        if secondOperationValueVAR == "/"{
            topFormula = -(secondXValueVAR) + sqrt(Double(bSquared) - (4 * firstXValueVAR * constantValueVAR))
            bottomFormula = 2 * firstXValueVAR
            totalX = topFormula / bottomFormula

              print(squaredValue)

            topFormula2 = -(secondXValueVAR) - sqrt(Double(bSquared) - (4 * firstXValueVAR * constantValueVAR))
            bottomFormula = 2 * firstXValueVAR
            totalX2 = topFormula2 / bottomFormula

            print(topFormula)
            print(topFormula2)
            print(bottomFormula)

            print("X = \(totalX) & \(totalX2)")
        }
        if secondOperationValueVAR == "+"{
            topFormula = -(secondXValueVAR) + sqrt(Double(bSquared) - (4 * firstXValueVAR * constantValueVAR))
            bottomFormula = 2 * firstXValueVAR
            totalX = topFormula / bottomFormula

              print(squaredValue)

            topFormula2 = -(secondXValueVAR) - sqrt(Double(bSquared) - (4 * firstXValueVAR * constantValueVAR))
            bottomFormula = 2 * firstXValueVAR
            totalX2 = topFormula2 / bottomFormula

            print(topFormula)
            print(topFormula2)
            print(bottomFormula)

            print("X = \(totalX) & \(totalX2)")
        }
        if secondOperationValueVAR == "-"{
            topFormula = -(secondXValueVAR) + sqrt(Double(bSquared) - (4 * firstXValueVAR * constantValueVAR))
            bottomFormula = 2 * firstXValueVAR
            totalX = topFormula / bottomFormula

              print(squaredValue)

            topFormula2 = -(secondXValueVAR) - sqrt(Double(bSquared) - (4 * firstXValueVAR * constantValueVAR))
            bottomFormula = 2 * firstXValueVAR
            totalX2 = topFormula2 / bottomFormula

            print(topFormula)
            print(topFormula2)
            print(bottomFormula)

            print("X = \(totalX) & \(totalX2)")
        }

    }
    if operations.contains(secondOperationValue.text!){
        secondOperationValueVAR = secondOperationValue.text!
    }



}
@IBAction func GoAction(sender: AnyObject) {
    updateValues()
}
```

Comment: general question: have you checked what happens in the user enters text into your textfields?

Comment: Did you tried an breakpoint and step by step check in the code?

Comment: Hi Andy. There's a very good answer below that seems, unfortunately, unreplied to. Did it help you at the time? If you can reply to it, vote on it, or accept it, that is generally thought to be good practice here. Better late than never?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The key issue is that you are using `sqrt`, which cannot handle negative numbers, because the result is an imaginary number. So, it's telling that it is "not a number" (`nan`). For example, `3 - sqrt(4)` is `1`, but `3 - sqrt(-4)` is really `3 - 2i`. But the `sqrt` function cannot do that for you, so you either have to use a library that handles imaginary numbers, or handle this manually yourself.

A couple of issues unrelated to the `nan` error:

2. You are setting `firstXValueInt` (and the other similar `Int` variables) based upon the contents of `firstXValueVAR`, but then, after you do that, you re-retrieve `firstXValueVAR` from the `UITextField`. That seems backwards. First get the values from the text field, and then start doing your calculations.
3. You are converting your text field value to a `Double` and then converting it to an `Int` so you can square it using a bitwise shift operator. Sure, you can do that if you're assured that the values will never contain non-integer values, but that's a huge constraint to impose just so you can enjoy the efficiency of the bitwise shift operation. Plus that bitwise operation is not doing what I think you think it does. The `<< 2` is equivalent to multiplying by four, not squaring it.
4. And if you're really that concerned about efficiency, I wouldn't recalculate the discriminant multiple times. Personally, I'd suggest losing this integer conversion and avoid a whole category of possible problems.
5. I'm not understanding why you appear to be repeating the code to  calculate of `totalX` and `totalX2` four times on the basis of the value of the `firstOperationValue`. And if you're going to do that, I'd either shift to a `if`-`else if` pattern (or, better, a `switch` statement) and then have a `default` clause to detect if none of the four expected values are found.

Anyway, if I wanted the roots of this quadratic formula, I'd do something like:

```
let a = Double(firstXValue.text!)!
let b = Double(secondXValue.text!)!
let c = Double(constantValue.text!)!
let bSquared = b * b
let discriminant = bSquared - (4 * a * c)
let isImaginary = discriminant < 0
let discrimimantAbsSqrt = sqrt(fabs(discriminant))

if isImaginary {
    print("X = (\(-b) + \(discrimimantAbsSqrt)i)/\(2*a) & (\(-b) - \(discrimimantAbsSqrt)i)/\(2*a)")
} else {
    let topFormula = -b + discrimimantAbsSqrt
    let bottomFormula = 2 * a
    let totalX = topFormula / bottomFormula

    let topFormula2 = -b - discrimimantAbsSqrt
    let totalX2 = topFormula2 / bottomFormula

    print("X = \(totalX) & \(totalX2)")
}
```

Note, the above retires all of those properties and uses only local variables (other than the `UITextField` controls). You can minimize unintended consequences by making sure you only use properties where you really need them, and I'd personally keep all the calculations as local variables. Personally, I'd also eschew the use of forced unwrapping (the `!`) and do conditional binding to gracefully handle `nil` values, but that's up to you.